# How can I ignore errors with specific keywords in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am aware that I can ignore **ALL** errors like so:

```
command 2>/dev/null
```

But I want to ignore only specific errors.

For example, if I run:

```
cp file
```

I get the error:

**cp: missing destination file operand after ‘file’**

How can I ignore an error if it has the string "operand" in it?

If an error **DOES NOT** contain the string "operand", I would like the error printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cp file 2>&1 | grep -v operand
```

Comment: Since `bash` 4, also the shoretened `&>` can be used to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr`

Comment: Here is another example usecase:

`(tools/scripts/simulate-fail.sh 2>&1 | grep -v 'Cannot publish because xyz')`

And in `simulate-fail.sh`: 

`(echo 'Cannot publish over existing' >&2) && exit 1`